# Make a for loop method with if statements return the correct "return" without array?

Tags: java, loops, methods, return

I am doing some java exercises and I am trying to make a method that counts to 100 and prints the number each time the for loop "loops". 
The exception is that it will print "Fizz" when the number is divisible by 3 and "Buzz" when the number is divisible by 5. 
Now, I have three return types in my method that is gonna return a String. However, the error says I do not return a value. I am aware that I have to make it return a String outside the for loop but I am having some trouble figuring out how I should get to return the value that I want. 
I am also aware that I could use arrays or even arrayList to fix this problem but I think its possible without that and I would like to try doing so. 
Any help would be very appreciated! 
Here is the code:

```
package etcOvaningar;

public class ovning1 {

    public static String fizz ="Fizz!";
    public static String buzz ="Buzz!";

    public static String countDown(){
    for (int number = 0; number < 100; number++){
        if (number%3 == 0){
            return fizz;
        }
        else if (number%5 == 0){
            return buzz;
        }
        else
            return String.valueOf(number);
    }
           //I need to insert a return here I suppose, but I want the correct return from the if and else //statements
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that `return` **kills** your method, and the program _returns_ to where it was called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't "return" in the loop, but rather **print**. When you return, the method exits, and the loop loops no more. If you simply print the necessary text, the for loop will continue to loop until it reaches its natural end condition.

```
public static void countDown(){
  for (int number = 0; number < 100; number++){
    if (number % (3*5) == 0) {
        System.out.println("fizzbuzz");
    } else 
    if (number % 3 == 0){
        System.out.println("fizz");
    } else
    if (number % 5 == 0){
        System.out.println("buzz");
    }
  }
}
```

Note as per Martin Dinov, this method should be declared to return `void`, nothing.

Comment: And in your method's signature have:
`public static void countDown()`

Comment: Ah wow how easy it was! You make me feel so bad at this haha! Thank you both for your quick replies. I thought that if I had void it wouldn't actually print something. Guess I should tinker around before asking. Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: If this works for you, then please accept this as a correct answer.

Comment: I can't accept it right now apparently. Must wait 2 minutes more :p... idk why ^^. If possible I would like to rep Martin Dinov too but can't find any button for that :/

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't compile because method countdown needs return value below the for loop.

However whatever you return value you put below the for loop won't matter because your countdown method will always return "Fizz!"

Comment: Yes I was aware that I needed a return value below the for loop. My problem was how to get the if return values down there respectively. But the solution by Hovercraft Full Of Eels and Martin Dinov solved that perfectly. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do what you want to do. Perhaps, more of what you really should be doing.

```
private static String fizz ="Fizz!";
private static String buzz ="Buzz!";    

public static void main(String[] args){
    for (int number = 0; number < 100; number++){
        String word = checkNumber(number);
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}

private static String checkNumber(int number){
    String value = "";
    if (number%3 == 0){
        value += fizz;
    }
    if (number%5 == 0){
        value += buzz;
    }
    if (value.isEmpty()) {
        value = String.valueOf(number);
    }
    return value;
}
```

**Points to note:**

- Start your methods and fields as `private` and upgrade their visibility as you further develop your program and your needs change. This helps keep the code clean and the exposure to the minimum.
- Try not to have print statements in methods (unless they are specifically designed for printing messages). They should take an input, process the input and return an output. Nothing more, nothing less.
- Understand the difference between `if / else if / else` and `if / if / if`. The number 15 is divisible by both 3 and 5.